# angular: replace &#8217 character from json

Tags: json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm building a mobile app that pulls data from json. Some of the texts come with strange characters like & # 8217. How do I change it? Here is my code:

```
$http.jsonp( postsApi ).
success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    $scope.posts = data;



   $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.content);

  console.log( data );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This strange characters are html encoded characters, if you bind you content on your page, using `ng-bind-html="content"` it will display the corect html code on your page, you have no need to change them.

For example, `&#8217` is the encoded version of the quote `'`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have strings containing html. I would recommend that you read up on html character references, for example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML and then find a library to decode it.